# Simple Javascript validation function

Tags: javascript

I do not have any JavaScript experience and would like some assistance in creating a function as I am not sure on how to do it.

I would like to create a Function that validates that x between 1 and 17 it can also be equal to 1 and 17

If the value is not valid a simple messagebox/alert could be used to notify the user

I know this is a really stupid question but thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function like that would look something like:

```
function validateNumber(n) {
  var ok = n >= 1 && n <= 17;
  if (!ok) alert('The value is not valid. Values from 1 to 17 are allowed.');
  return ok;
}
```

You can call it, and you get the status back if you want to use it for something:

```
if (validateNumber(x)) {
  // the number was valid
} else {
  // the number wasn't valid
}
```